# Why is my Azure mobile app not returning any data?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have been following a tutorial about Azure Mobile Apps'Easy Tables (https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/).  Everything has been going quite well and I managed to get to the point of testing my app which doesn't seem to return any data and I don't know why, I don't recieve any errors either which is making the tracing of this problem more difficult.

Ok to start with I have my Azure database (configured to allow access to Azure Services) and I have my table created and working using EasyTables.  I used the Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) application to test my API and to ensure data was returned from my database using `https://myproject.azurewebsites.net/tables/users` which returned my data as json.

My database table is called `users` and it's structure is quite basic (for testing) with two columns `id` and `FirstName`.  I have populated my table with dummy data which I have proven can be returned from my azure uri using Postman.

That's the ground work to get running, here is a snapshot of my project hierarchy.

### [image]

**MyProject/Model/users.cs**

This is the entity data which is named to match the table in the database.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class users
    {

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
        public string id { get; set; }       

        public string FirstName {get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MyProject/Services/AzureService.cs**

Crucially we have `public async Task<IEnumerable<users>> GetUsers()` task here which is and triggers Inialization task (which is where the app url is defined).

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyProject;
using System.IO;
using Plugin.Connectivity;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AzureService))]
namespace MyProject
{
    public class AzureService
    {
        public MobileServiceClient Client { get; set; } = null;

        IMobileServiceSyncTable<users> userTable;       
        public async Task Initialize()
        {
            if (Client?.SyncContext?.IsInitialized ?? false)
                return;

            var appUrl = "https://myproject.azurewebsites.net";

            //Create our client

            Client = new MobileServiceClient(appUrl);


            //InitialzeDatabase for path
            var path = "syncstore.db";
            //path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, path);

            //setup our local sqlite store and intialize our table
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);

            //Define table
            store.DefineTable<users>();


            //Initialize SyncContext
            await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

            //Get our sync table that will call out to azure
            userTable = Client.GetSyncTable<users>();


        }

        public async Task SyncUsers()
        {
            try
            {

                await userTable.PullAsync("allUsers", userTable.CreateQuery());

                await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to sync users, that is alright as we have offline capabilities: " + ex);
            }

        }

        //
        //Get Users
        public async Task<IEnumerable<users>> GetUsers()
        {
            await Initialize();
            await SyncUsers();

            return await userTable.ToEnumerableAsync(); ;

        }   
    }
}
```

**MyProject/View/UserList.xaml**

I kept this short and minimalistic for the purposes of testing.  A simple list with it's source set to UsersList (which is an Observable collection within the ViewModel).  Each item in the list is bound to `FirstName`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject;assembly=MyProject"
             x:Class="MyProject.UserList"
             Title="UserList">
        <ListView x:Name="userList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}"
                  IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                  RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadUsersCommand}"
                  Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="15,5,0,0">
                            <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"  />
                        </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>        
</ContentPage>
```

**MyProject/View/UserList.xaml.cs**

This simply states that UserList is bound to the viewmodel and when the list appears trigger the load users command from within the viewmodel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Plugin.Connectivity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class UserList : ContentPage
    {
        UsersViewModel vm;

        public UserList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = vm = new UsersViewModel();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            vm.LoadUsersCommand.Execute(null);            
        }       
    }
}
```

**MyProject/ViewModel/UsersViewModel.cs**

This file does the most work, the view model has the observable defined and the Load Users command too.

```
using System;
using MvvmHelpers;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class UsersViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        AzureService azureService;
        public UsersViewModel()
        {
            azureService = DependencyService.Get<AzureService>();
        }

        public ObservableRangeCollection<users> UserList { get; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<users>();

        string loadingMessage;
        public string LoadingMessage
        {
            get { return loadingMessage; }
            set { SetProperty(ref loadingMessage, value); }
        }

        ICommand  loadUsersCommand;
        public ICommand LoadUsersCommand =>
            loadUsersCommand ?? (loadUsersCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadUsersCommandAsync())); 

        async Task ExecuteLoadUsersCommandAsync()
        {
            try 
            {                
                LoadingMessage = "Loading Users...";
                IsBusy = true;
                var users = await azureService.GetUsers();
                UserList.ReplaceRange(users);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("OH NO!" + ex);

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Sync Error", "Unable to sync users, you may be offline", "OK");
            } 
            finally 
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

I popped a few break points in when I run the app to see if I can get to the bottom of the problem, the lack of error means I have no frame of reference to work from.

The current order in which events are triggering is as follows (based on breakpoints I put in):

1. `public ObservableRangeCollection<users> UserList { get; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<users>();` - UserViewModel
2. `azureService = DependencyService.Get<AzureService>();` - UserViewModel
3. `var users = await azureService.GetUsers();` - UserViewModel
4. `await Initialize();` - AzureService
5. `public async Task Initialize()` - AzureService
6. `await SyncUsers();` - AzureServce
7. `public async Task SyncUsers()` - AzureService
8. `return await userTable.ToEnumerableAsync(); ;` - AzureService
9. `UserList.ReplaceRange(users);` - UserViewModel

The list is then loaded on my MacBook pro using the simulator but it's empty, no data at all.  Can anyone help me understand why I can't get my data?  Are their break points I should put in place and check if certain items exist?

Like I say without an actual error this is a tough one but it could also be something really simple, any help is appreciated.

**Update**

Further to my initial investigation I've added an `if` statement to my code, specifically within the `OnAppearing` method in `UserList.xaml.cs`.  The code I added checks of the `UserList` collection in `UserViewModel.cs` is 0 or not.

```
 protected override async void OnAppearing()
 {
     base.OnAppearing();

     if (vm.UserList.Count == 0)
         vm.LoadUsersCommand.Execute(null);
     else
     {
         ...
     }
     vm.LoadUsersCommand.Execute(null);
 }
```

What is interesting about this is that the `UserList` is always coming back with 0.  So the problem looks like it's in this line of code which sits in `UsersViewModel.cs`

`public ObservableRangeCollection<users> UserList { get; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<users>();`

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is this bit correct `ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}"` ? Everywhere else you call it `UserList`?

Comment: Oww a good spy there @Flexicoder thanks.  I've now changed it but it's not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can see is that you have the id column renamed to Id - on the client, it needs to be id (lower-case).

There are a couple of other mistakes in there, but they should be readily found with a debugger.  I see one of them has already been pointed out.

Comment: Thanks @adrian-hall  I've changed the renamed column to lowercase `id` and I've also corrected the above mentioned list binding name.  None have helped.  What do you think about this `ObersvableRangeCollection` `UserList` being 0 all the time? could that be to blame?  The app seems to work it's just not getting any data and my conditional statement is always met because userlist is always 0 too.  It's like there is just one piece missing that's preventing it working.

Comment: I'd have to step through the project.  I'd take a look at the userlist that is being given to ReplaceRange() and ensure there are records there.  Also, I'd look at where you call SyncUsers()... I don't see the call to actually synchronize the database anywhere in your provided code.  Pull up the log stream in the Azure Portal and ensure you are actually doing a service pull.